# Session attribute access and converting to int?

Tags: java, session, servlets, casting

I have stored user id in Session using following command in Servlet:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("user", user.getId());
```

Now, I want to access that user id from another Servlet:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
int userid = (int) session.getAttribute("user"); // This is not working

OR

User user = new User();
user.setId(session.getAttribute("user")); This ain't possible (Object != int)
```

Question:

1. How can I cast to int and send the id to DAO for SELECT statement

Comment: I am getting following Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: app.models.User cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Comment: I used this Integer userid = (Integer) session.getAttribute("user");

Comment: @a k what's the return type of `user.getId()` ?

Comment: public int getId() {return id;}

Comment: public int getId() {return id;} and changed to Integer and its showing (java.lang.NullPointerException) now

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Even if you saved an `int`, that method expects an Object so your `int` will become an `Integer` due to auto-boxing. Try to cast it back to `Integer` and it should be fine:

```
int userid = (Integer) session.getAttribute("user");
```

However, if the attribute is null you will get a `NullPointerException` here, so maybe it's better to go with `Integer` all the way:

```
Integer userid = (Integer) session.getAttribute("user");
```

After this, you can safely check if `userid` is `null`.

---

EDIT:
In response to your comments, here's what I mean by "check for null".

```
Integer userid = (Integer) session.getAttribute("user");
User user = null;
if (userid != null) {
    user = new UserDAO().getUser(userid);
}
// here user will be null if no userid has been stored on the session,
// and it wil be loaded from your persistence layer otherwise.
```

Comment: I am getting NullPointerException after second statement too.

Comment: After it ? You mean, you have the `Integer userid` assigned and then what ? Do you check it for null ? If not and you try call anything on it or you try to assign it to some `int` or pass it to some method expecting `int`, the NPE is natural. But the line itself cannot really throw a NPE. If the userid is null after reading it from the session it means nobody has stored it there yet.

Comment: I am passing it in UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();  and   userDAO.getUser(userid);

Comment: I suppose your `getUser()` expects an `int`. Check the `userid` for null and if it is (you have nothing stored on the session as "user), avoid that call (or use a default value instead, if it makes sense: -1 or 0 or whatever).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not good at JAVA but I used to do it like
`Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("user").toString())`

Try once, but just be sure to `check null` for `session.getAttribute("user")` before calling `toString`

Comment: There's an `Integer` saved as session attribute. Converting it to `String` and parsing back into an `int`/`Integer` doesn't get you much, does it ?

Comment: I'm not sure how `Object to int` conversion works. If Object is `converted to Integer` and then `intValue()` is used, results might be good. As already told, I'm not good at JAVA.

Comment: In C++ it is surely not going to work, because `Object class` will not be of same size in stack as `int`

Comment: It's not really `Object` to `int`; autoboxing is actually `Integer` to `int` (or `int` to `Integer`), the same for `long` and `Long` and basically all the primitive wrappers. It means you can assign an `Integer` value to an `int` variable, without caring of `intValue()` or you can assign an `int` value to an `Integer` reference, without wrapping as `new Integer(value)`. When a supertype of `Integer` is expected (`Object` in this case), `int` will be passed as `Integer`. It's just syntax sugar added in Java 1.5. How else would it be possible to pass an `int` to `setAttribute(String, Object)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Java has [`Integer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) wrapper class , you can store int value in an Object of `Integer`

```
//setting
Integer intObj = new Integer(intVal);
session.setAttribute("key",intObj);
//fetching
Integer intObj = (Integer) session.getAttribute("key");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `int userid = (Integer) session.getAttribute("user");`

Comment: getting java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @a k Not sure why it's null but you can do 
`int userid = session.getAttribute("user") == null ? (Integer) session.getAttribute("user") : 0 ;` where `0` would be the default value if sesson returns null. but you still need to figure out why it's null if it's not supposed to be null.

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer userid = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("user"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("String").toString())
```

Comment: Why `"String"` as `getAttribute()` arg? Should be `"user"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int userid = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("user").toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it worked for me: 
`HttpSession session = request.getSession(); 
if (session.getAttribute("user") != null) { 
userid = ((Integer) session.getAttribute("user")).intValue(); } else { userid = 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying two strings from session:

```
int z = Integer.parseInt((String)session.getAttribute("sintelestis"));
int y = Integer.parseInt((String)session.getAttribute("_embadon_akinitou"));
System.out.println("Ο Συνολικός Φόρος είναι: "+ (z*y));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code :

```
 int userId=Integer.parseInt((String)session.getAttribute("user"));
```