# How to typecast object to int in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I need to be able to compare the value that is in an object to an int, but I can't seem to get the typecasting working.  I have tried all the methods described here: [Session attribute access and converting to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031278/session-attribute-access-and-converting-to-int) but they all give me a null pointer exception.  Here is the code I have that's not working.

Here is the code that puts values into the session.

```
<script>sessionStorage.clickcount=1;</script>
<input type ="hidden" name="ttmp" value="222" id="ttmp" />
<script>document.getElementById('ttmp').value = sessionStorage.clickcount;</script>
```

This was tried with the input line before and after the script.

```
<%
  String value = request.getParameter("ttmp");
  if (value != null) {
    session.setAttribute("test", value);
  }
  Integer userid = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("test").toString());
  ...
  if (userid == 1) {
  ...
  }
%>
```

Comment: Strings aren't Integers, so casting a String to Integer doesn't make sense.  Check out `Integer.parseInt` if you want to *convert* a string to a number.

Comment: This code will throw `NullPointerException` if `session` is `null`.  The version with `parseInt` will throw the same exception if `session.getAttribute("test")` returns `null`.  Are you certain that you've called `session.setAttribute("test", someInteger)`?

Comment: If you are sure the string contains only digist then why don't you use  `Integer.parseInteger()`

Comment: I have tried that but it gives me a different error.

Answer (score 2):

try this `Integer.parseInt((String)session.getAttribute("test"))`

```
<%
  String value = request.getParameter("ttmp");
  if (value != null) {
    session.setAttribute("test", value);
  }
  Integer userid = Integer.parseInt((String)session.getAttribute("test"));
  ...
  if (userid == 1) {
  ...
  }
%>
```

Comment: That gave me this error: PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
no suitable method found for parseInt(java.lang.Object)
    method java.lang.Integer.parseInt(java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (actual argument java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String by method invocation conversion)
    method java.lang.Integer.parseInt(java.lang.String,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: @user2532973 cast it into string then convert,check my updated answer

Comment: Well now I get a different error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Comment: @user2532973 are you sure session.getAttribute("test") is not null.I think session.getAttribute("test")return null.check it

Comment: I set the value of ttmp to 2 but I'm still getting the Null error

Comment: @user2532973 I am sure session.getAttribute("test") gives you null.Print it using out.println(session.getAttribute("test"));

Answer (score 1):

Try this now.

```
<%
String value = request.getParameter("ttmp");
if (value != null) {
session.setAttribute("test", value);
}
int userid=0;
if ((session.getAttribute("test") != null) && (session.getAttribute("test") != "")) 
{
    userid = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("test").toString());
}
%>
```

Comment: String value = request.getParameter("ttmp");

value variable should contain some number that can later be converted to an Integer.

Comment: I set the value of ttmp to 2 but I'm still getting the Null error